# Restrict CiviCase Status changes

Tags: civicase

Does anyone know how to restrict available CiviCase Status types based on what the current status is?

I.e. I want not to be able to go to "application rejected" until it has passed through "application awaiting review".

If this isn't possible out of the box, does anybody know what would be involved in developing that functionality?

Thank you,

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form validation hook:
http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_validateForm

When you say "until it has passed through...", in the hook you could look up the prior activity revisions.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest is probably a little jQuery wrangling, you can see an example in this extension which sets a default case status based on the case type: https://github.com/PUMNL/nl.pum.casestatus